# Why are Web -App permissions no longer in the manifest?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, permissions, geolocation, manifest

Can someone please introduce the [Permissions](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/) authors to the [Manifest](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/) authors?

When Mozilla had it so right so long ago why did they start from scratch? It is most often highly desirable to ask for permissions at Web App initialization/install time, not when the user finally gets around to using the microphone. Let the manifest declare these intentions and reduce friction/surprises for the user later on. How would a ServiceWorker request privilege if the UA is not there or in the background?

A case in point [and a bad idea.](https://github.com/w3c/permissions/issues/145) Any Web App installed on the homescreen is implicitly granted some permissions fullscreen being one of them.

Anyway, my question is this "Why are permission request declarations no longer in the manifest?" another question, of course, is why do these specifications always seem to be an exercise in perpetual motion? Time for a deliverable perhaps?

I mention it here as I hoped it would stir thought as to how to get user approval for background geolocation. (And the fact that I'm banned from W3C forums :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Development and Design jury is in and the verdict is only prompt for permission when you need to use it and hopefully have some user-discernible  context around why the access is needed. Apple design guidelines are in agreeance

Some [good](https://discourse.wicg.io/t/background-geolocation-gps-support/2146/10) background discussion and [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/permission-ux) seems to be a well argued case.